# Added Ckeditor to textarea why is my submit button disabled?

Tags: html, angularjs, ckeditor

I added ckeditor to my form's text area and all features work fine, no error message, yet my submit button remains disabled (color is muted and displays the crossed out circle cursor when hovering).

I'm using angular/firebase and routing to a template from my js file.  Really not sure why, with out the Ckeditor script and code the submit/publish button works fine.  Adding ckeditor disables it.  Feel like there's some compatibility issues with another script.

main index.html

```
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>My AngularJS App</title>
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div ng-view></div>

   <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main/main.js"></script>
    <script src="login/login.js"></script>
    <script src="register/register.js"></script>
    <script src="welcome/welcome.js"></script>
   <script src="addPost/addPost.js"></script>
   <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
    <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
   <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>

  </body>
```

Template addPost.html

```
     <body ng-controller="AddPostCtrl">
    <div class="container" >

     <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="AddPost()">
     <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Create Post</legend>

   <!-- Text input-->
   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtTitle">Title</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
 <input id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle" ng-model="article.title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control input-md">
  </div>
 </div>

    <!-- Textarea -->
     <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="txtPost">Post</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="txtPost" ng-model="article.post" name="txtPost" ></textarea>
     <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtPost' );
    </script>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="singlebutton" ng-disabled="!article.title || !article.post" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Publish" />
  </div>
 </div>

  </fieldset>
    </form>
   </div><!-- /.container -->
     </body>
```

addPost.js

```
     'use strict';

     angular.module('myApp.addPost', ['ngRoute'])

      .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/addPost', {
     templateUrl: 'addPost/addPost.html',
      controller: 'AddPostCtrl'
     });
    }])

   .controller('AddPostCtrl',['$scope','$firebase','$location','CommonProp',function($scope,$firebase, $location,CommonProp) {
   if(!CommonProp.getUser()){
   $location.path('/home');
 }

    $scope.logout = function(){
    CommonProp.logoutUser();
  }

     $scope.AddPost = function(){
     var title = $scope.article.title;
       var post = $scope.article.post;

     var firebaseObj = new Firebase("myblog-xxxx.../Articles");
       var fb = $firebase(firebaseObj);

      fb.$push({ title: title,post: post,emailId:  CommonProp.getUser() }).then(function(ref) {
      console.log(ref); 
        $location.path('/welcome');
      }, function(error) {
      console.log("Error:", error);
    });

     }
  }]);
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the conditions to disable the button? `<input id="singlebutton" ng-disabled="!article.title" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Publish" />`

Comment: Yeah Just realized it was a form validation issue.  Removing ng-disabled="!article.title || !article.post" enables the submit button but does not function properly.  Seems that when ckeditor's script is added it changes the input field names so they're no longer article.title, article.post which explains the disabled submit button.  Trying to figure how to keep ckeditor from changing the input fields so they don't differ from my ng-model variables in my addpost function.